# Диетологи рассказали о зимнем меню

Tags: согласование

"Диетологи рассказали о зимнем меню" - верное ли согласование с *меню*?

Answer (score 1):

Да, все верно. Меню - несклоняемое существительное среднего рода.

Answer (score 1):

**МЕНЮ**, неизм.; ср. [франц. menu ― мелкий, детальный]. 1. Подбор кушаний, блюд для обеда, завтрака и т.п. В утреннее м. входит два яйца и стакан кофе.

Диетологи рассказали о зимнем  меню. **Согласование в ед.ч, ср.р., П.п.**

Единственное число ― подбор блюд на зиму.